# changing the order of double integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am a little bit stucked about the changing the order of a double integration.

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{t-n}^{t}f(n,s)dsdn$

I try to represent the upper and lower bounds by a graphic but as I have infinity, I can not. What can it be the way to follow ?

Thanks in advance.

It can be silly but as I don't specify my function $f(n,s)$ is it possible to write ;

$\displaystyle \int_{t-n}^{t}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(n,s)dnds$

or will it be totaly wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose $t$ is a fixed number. I recommend you to sketch a $ns$ plane. We know that $t-n<s<t$. So, draw the line $s=t-n$ and the line $s=t$. Since $0<n<\infty$ then you have a portion of the $ns$ of the plane as the region on which you will integrate. That region looks like a triangular region, but it's unbounded of course. If you want to integrate over that region but in the other way then you can notice that $n$ will be now bounded by $n<t-s$ and $s$ will be bounded by $t$.

The new integral should be
$$\int_{-\infty}^t\int_{t-s}^\infty f(n,s)\,dn\,ds.$$

Comment: Thanks so much, that was so clear. I think this one comes from Fubini's theorem. @Vladimir Vargas

Comment: @optimalcontrol Yes, it is a 'natural' theorem, and very useful of course.